# Array in QueryParams wiremock

Tags: wiremock, wiremock-standalone, wiremock-record

I need to pass through queryParams  in wireMock

```
Person=[{age=6,name=AAA}]
```

I've been getting 404  when  I  test in the curl request. Aly leads would be appreciated.

Only thing i know is

```
"Person": {
    "matches": "^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]*$"
  }
```

I'm not sure on how to validate the array.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex matching is incorrect. The value of Person is `[{age=6,name=AAA}]`, so your matcher will need to capture all of that to be considered a match. You've used some special characters that need escaping, as well as an invalid capture group (which I don't think we really need here.) Without any more guidance from your post on what you precisely need to match, here's two rough ideas:

```
"Person": {
  "matches": "^\[.*\]$"
}
```

The above just matches *any* character, *an unlimited amount* of times, between brackets.

```
"Person": {
  "matches": "^\[\{age=\d*,name=\w*\}\]$"
}
```

The above matches *any* digit character, an unlimited amount of times, as well as *any* word character, an unlimited amount of times, so long as the rest of the value looks like `[{age=,name=}]`.

I would advise you to take a look at a regex tool to work on forming these. [My personal favorite is regex101.](https://regex101.com/)